# Change child's state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

```
function App(){
  const [selectedLang, setSelectedLang] = useState(0);
  const [langList, setLangList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    const list = [];
    /* i18n.options.supportedLngs is ['en', 'ko'] */
    i18n.options.supportedLngs.map((item, i)=>{
      list.push(item);
      /* Set selectedLang to i18n's default language.(Default is 'ko')*/
      if(item === i18n.language){
        setSelectedLang(i);
      }
    })
    setLangList(list);
  }, [])
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.debug("langList :", langList, ",", selectedLang); // <- It print correctly ['en', 'ko'], 1
  }, [langList, selectedLang])
  return(
    <Child defaultIndex={selectedLang} childList={langList}/>
  )
}


function Child(props){
  const {defaultIndex, childList} = props;
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

  useState(()=>{
    setSelected(defaultIndex);
  },[])
  return(
    <div>
      {childList[selected]} //<- But it print 'en'.
    </div>
  )

}
```

The code above is a simplified version of my code.

Currently i18n defaults to 'ko'. I want to display 'ko' in Child by setting `selectedLang` to 'ko's index in `App`, and giving the index of 'ko' and the entire language array as props to `Child`.

However, `Child`'s `selected` and `defaultIndex` doesn't seem to change from a state initialized with `useState(0)`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setSelected` need to be called after changing `defaultIndex` in `Child` component.

And you didn't use proper hook.

```js
  useEffect(()=>{
    setSelected(defaultIndex);
  },[defaultIndex])
```

Comment: Maybe  it should be useEffect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react context to achieve this:
First make a Lang provider in app.js

```js
const LangContext = React.createContext('ko');

function App() {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("ko");
  return (
    <LangContext.Provider value={[lang, setLang]}>
      <Toolbar />
    </LangContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Then in any child component you can use :

```js
function Button() {
  const [lang, setLang]= useContext(LangContext);
  return (
    <button onClick={()=>{setLang('en')}}>
      {lang}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Any change in context will propagate in all components using useContext.

Read more here : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext